# Sort "find" by parent directories before subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to find all the text files in all subdirectories of folder *Temp* and I've been using:

```
find Temp/ -name *.txt | sort
```

But I need it to sort by parent folders before subdirectories.
Meaning if I have two files `Temp/1/a.txt`, it shows up before `Temp/z.txt`, but I need it the other way around.
How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried sort -n and sort -V -k1 to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the number of slashes.

```
find Temp/ -name '*.txt' \
| perl -pe 'print tr{/}{}, "\t"' \
| LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1n -k2 \
| cut -f2-
```

The `tr` operator returns the number of matches, i.e. the number of slashes in the string in Perl.

The `sort` then sorts the lines numercially and `cut` removes the number from each line.

Comment: Thank you! This works great if I add "export LC_ALL=C" at the top

Comment: @Nameles36: True, adding it before `sort` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with AWK gsub too :

```sh
find Temp/ -name *.txt | awk '{print gsub(/\//,"/")"|"$0; }' | sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2 | sed 's/^[^|]*|//'
```

The gsub function returns the number of '/' substitutions, indicating the path depth of each entry (not perfectly, but it should be enough for your needs). We use that to sort the paths in depth order first then alphabetical order and remove the path depth with sed.

**EDIT:** For reference If you need to order by parent folder order first then depth order then alphabetical order :

```sh
find Temp/ -name *.txt \
| awk '{parent=$0;gsub(/\/[^\/]*$/,"",parent);depth=gsub(/\//,"/",$0); print parent "|" depth "|"$0; }' \
| sort -t'|' -k1 -k2,2n -k3 \
| sed 's/^[^|]*|[^|]*|//'
```

Here AWK output parent folder followed by a pipe separator and path depth, another pipe separator and the full path. We sort then simply and remove parent folder and depth with sed.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ tree .
.
├── 1
│   └── a.txt
├── a.txt
└── z.txt
```

You can use a pipe with ruby to do a two key sort based on 1) count of `/` and 2) the file name:

```
find . -name '*.txt' \
| ruby -e 'fs=$<.readlines.sort_by{|f| [-f.count("/"), f[/[^\/]+$/]]} ; END{puts fs.join("")}'
```

Prints:

```
1 directory, 3 files
./1/a.txt
./a.txt
./z.txt
```